# How can I see the new changed configurations in the configure mode?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

In JUNOS, and in the configure mode, I edited something, 
now if I want to quit the edit mode, how can I check what I have new changed?

my questions are bellow:

1. show the changed configurations(not all the configure).
2. how can I call off my new changed configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> show the changed configurations(not all the configure).

You can do that with `show | compare`. If you want to see *all* changes, make sure you go to the top of the configuration first using `top`. If you're already editing a section (for example since you did `edit protocols bgp` first) and you run `show | compare` you will only see changes in that section.

> how can I call off my new changed configurations?

Go to the top of the configuration and then do a rollback to go back to the last saved configuration:

```
top
rollback
```

And then quit configuration mode:

`quit configuration-mode`

Juniper has a free PDF which explains these things and many more CLI related things: [Day One: Exploring the Junos CLI](https://www.juniper.net/us/en/training/jnbooks/day-one/fundamentals-series/cli/).